# How to install extra packages for jython that comes with Android

Tags: android, python, jython

I have an installation of Android sdk on my machine. And I am using monkeyrunner to execute a bunch of code.

Now the problem is I also need py-serial package that comes with CPython in my code (that I am running with Jython). I tried adding `sys.path.append('C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages')` to my Jython code so that I can use serial package, but that failed miserably.

My question is how can I use external CPython packages with Jython that comes with Android sdk install?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) as a *drop-in* replacement for monkeyrunner.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import com.dtmilano.android.viewclient
>>> import serial
>>>
```